# How do I update a list in Sheme. I mean build items, on to a preexisting list , one at at time, use car

Tags: scheme

Given the following as input into Scheme procedure.

```
( define Ls ( list 'Apple 'Peach 'Pear 'Plum ) ) 
( define NewLs ( list '***HEAD ))
```

This is the output I need to get

```
( define Ls ( List 'Apple 'Peach 'Pear 'Plum ) ) 
( define NewLs ( List '***HEAD 'Apple 'Peach 'Pear 'Plum ) )
```

I need to append the items from LS to NewLs, but one at a time.

I have tried , append, append! set and set!

```
( define Ls ( list 'Apple 'Peach 'Pear 'Plum ) )
( define NewLs ( list '***HEAD ) )
;;;
( define Update_List
   ( lambda ( Ls ) 
     ( cond
          (( null? Ls ) 
             ( begin 
                ( display "\n\n ** END OF INPUT LIST *** \n\n" ) 
                ( quote() )))
          ( else
             ( begin
                ( append! NewLs ( car Ls ) )
                ( Update_List ( cdr Ls ) ) ) ) ) )
;;;
;;;
(Update_List Ls )
( exit )
```

I expect to see this

```
NewLs ( '***HEAD 'Apple 'Peach 'Pear 'Plum )
```

Comment: W hat is w ith the misplace d space s?

Answer (score 2):

I think you might be making it harder than it needs to be; in Scheme-ish, functional-programming style, we derive new lists from existing lists, using functions like `cons`.

Also, when writing in a functional programming style, we don't typically use destructive-update kinds of functions like `append!`, or any of those "!" functions.

You're on the right track, but try to think about the problem in terms of deriving a new list from the existing lists:  try to write a function which takes two input lists, say l1 and l2, and produces a list which is made up of all of the elements in l1, followed by all of the elements in l2.  Your `Update_List` function above shows that you are still thinking about the problem in terms of imperative programming, including destructive updating, and that's not typically how things get done in Scheme (and in functional programming in general.)

I know that is not a straight out answer to your question, but this feels like it might be a homework assignment, and I hope this gives you some hints about where to start/restart your work towards a solution.  Struggling a bit to get to the answer helps the principles to stick better and you learn them better that way.

### Edited:

My apologies to you:  I thought you might be a student working on a homework assignment, but then I saw your other question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54448872/how-do-i-change-a-list-code-included-with-the-answer)!

I still encourage you to consider what I have said above before reading further, for the learning happens with the struggle.

SO:  don't read any further before trying really hard to consider what I suggested above.

---

Here's how I would write a function like the one I described above:

```
(define append-lists
  (lambda (l1 l2) 
    (cond ((null? l1) l2)) ; if l1 is empty, then l2 is the "answer"
          (else 
           ; cons-truct a new list with the (car l1) 
           ; and the result of appending l2 to the 
           ; rest of l1, i.e., (cdr l1)
                (cons (car l1) 
                      (append-lists (cdr l1) l2) ) ) ) ) ) )
```